# Passing Data between fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've looked at various examples and dont quite understand exactly how this can be done.

I have 2 `fragments` each hosted by a seperate `Activity` and need to pass data between the two and update each other based on choices.

I have a clickable `Textview` in `fragment1` that should open `fragment2` and allow the user to select a choice from another list of `TextViews` each displaying a different option.

I want the choice of the user in fragment2 to update the text of the TextView in fragment1 based on the choice that was made.

I have a listener to start fragment 2 when the TextView is clicked:

```
v3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), FragmentActivity2.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

When I click a TextView in fragment2 I would like the fragment to close, return to fragment1 and update the text

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html. use a interface as a callback. All Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly.
. Communicate value to activity in fragment2. from activity 2 comunicate value to activity 1. you can use startActivtiyForResult from activity1

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to pass data between fragments is using listeners. You can implement one/two interface to exchange data (one for each activity). Your activity should implement an interface and then call the methdod in the inteface to update data:

```
public interface ChangeLinkListener {
   public void onLinkChange(String link);
}
```

In the onclick method:

```
(ChangeLinkListener)  getActivity()).onLinkChange(data.getLink());
```

Where onLinkChange is simply a method for example you could change the name as you prefer.
I've written a tutorial between passing data if you like you can look [here](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/03/android-fragment-tutorial-webview-example.html)